# Не переведены описания знаков

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В описании знаков нашел 3 непереведенных. Но вообще-то текст один и тот же, только цифирка меняется.

`Ask a well-received question on X separate days, and maintain a positive question record`
Используется в знаках Любознательный (Curious), Пытливый ум (Inquisitive) и Сократ (Socratic)

---

Вообще я еще несколько мест нашел, где перевода нет. Все сюда кидать?

Comment: На каждую страницу с непереведенным текстом создавайте отдельный вопрос на Мете. В ответах будут предлагаться варианты перевода. Кстати, свой тоже опубликуйте как ответ, чтобы за него можно было голосовать.

Comment: Впрочем, тут перевод уже был, но слетел. Проблема на стороне разработчиков SO.

Comment: да вот мне тоже казалось, что там все нормально было.... :)

Comment: На сколько я могу видеть, ошибка исправлена. Поправьте, пожалуйста, меня, если что-то упустил.

Comment: все переведено, все по-русски. спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Исправлено, [проверяйте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

---

Эти строки ([Tx:7524-7526](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/63370951?q=%22Ask%20a%20well-received%22)) уже переведены как

> Задавайте интересные вопросы в течение Х дней и поддерживайте положительный баланс голосов.

Похоже, что слетел перевод. Сообщу @NicolasChabanovsky

Answer (score 0):

Я бы перевел так:

> Х дней задавать минимум по одному качественному вопросу, поддерживая положительный баланс вопросов.