# Что такое "положительный баланс голосов" ("positive question record")?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, знаки

В описании знаков Любознательный (Curious), Пытливый ум (Inquisitive) и Сократ (Socratic)([Tx:7524-7526](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/63370951?q=%22Ask%20a%20well-received%22)):

> Задавайте интересные вопросы в течение Х дней и поддерживайте **положительный баланс голосов.**

В оригинале там:

> Ask a well-received question on X separate days, and maintain a **positive question record**

Вопросы:

- Что такое "positive question record"? Имеется в виду положительный рейтинг, качество вопросов (например, вопросы не закрыты и не дубли) или что-то ещё?
- Правильный ли у нас перевод?

Этот вопрос навеян другим: [Не переведены описания знаков](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1518/181472).

Comment: Разумеется это совсем неправильный перевод. [Вот объяснение расчета для этого термина](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262814/whats-the-meaning-of-well-received-question-and-of-maintaining-a-question)

Comment: @igumnov спасибо! Надо будет перевести этот ответ.

Comment: Тут пора ответ принимать.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Насколько можно понять по [этому посту на Мете SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges), подсчет устроен так:

```
boolean positive_question_record = ( 
    (total - downvoted - closed - deleted)
 / total >= 0.5);
```

- total - это все заданные вопросы, [включая удалённые](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234993/296059).

Так что текущий перевод нуждается в уточнении.

Comment: Там вроде бы `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5`? У вас тройка и нет деления.

Comment: @VladD про деление верно. Про тройку- там в тексте сказано, что плохие вопросы втройне учитываются.

Comment: @VladD про тройку неверно понял, исправил.

Comment: `текущий перевод нуждается в уточнении.` По-моему, оригинал нуждается в уточнение.

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку в формуле идёт речь о соотношении всех вопросов к удалённым/заминусованным/закрытым, предлагаю такой вариант перевода:

> Задавайте интересные вопросы в течение Х дней и поддерживайте общую одобрительную оценку ваших вопросов.

Смысл перевода в том, что мы говорим о *смысле* подсчёта («у вас нету большого количества заминусованных/удалённых вопросов, значит, к вашим вопросам сообщество хорошо относится»), не вдаваясь в скучные технические детали (из которых надо ещё *понять* суть).