# Не присвоился знак [Любознательный]

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, знаки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?
У меня уже выполнено 6 из 5)
Сколько еще надо задать вопросов, чтобы получить достижение?

Answer (score 4):

Нажмите на полоску и сможете увидеть причину:

> [image: не любознательный ещё]

О том, как осуществляется подсчёт можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1533/176217).