# Значение знака сократ

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, знаки

Что такое "интересный вопрос" в знаке [сократ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/89/socratic)?

Comment: По теме: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1532/15479

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik имхо, можно даже задубликатить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Интересный"* в данном случае - это имеющий положительный рейтинг.

А насчёт положительного баланса голосов [ответ тут](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1533/178988).

Comment: Хм.. что-то я засомневался. Именно положительный рейтинг или неотрицательный?

Comment: не, вроде именно positive, то есть положительный